# Combining Enum.map and Enum.each

Tags: pipe, elixir

I'm a neophyte of Elixir and I'm learning and reading something about list/enum usage and function piping.

I learned how to combine `Enum.map` and `Enum.each`, e.g. manipulating the content of a list and printing the results list to console through

```
people = ["Qui", "Quo", "Qua"]
people
    |> Enum.map(&String.upcase/1)
    |> Enum.map(&Hello.hello/1)
    |> Enum.each(&IO.puts/1)
```

I'm wondering if it exists a library function that combines `Enum.map` and `Enum.each` together: my idea is to *do something for list's each element **AND** return the untouched list*, in order to proceed piping function calls.
Sure, I can add side-effects to the function passed to `Enum.map`, but I don't like this approach very much and I would like to keep side effects explicitly separated from *functional* transformations.

I read `Enum` and `List`  documentation, but I can't figure how do this: `Enum.each` returns `:ok` and I can't find something similar returning the initial list.

So I implemented it myself as follows:

```
defmodule MyEnum do 
    def tee list, action do
        Enum.map(list, fn item -> 
            action.(item)
            item
        end)
    end
end
```

(***disclaimer*: sure, I added side effects to `map`, but I isolated this *dirtyness* into a function whose name should clarify my intent**) and rewrote the previous example as

```
people = ["Qui", "Quo", "Qua"]
people
    |> Enum.map(&String.upcase/1)
    |> Enum.map(&Hello.hello/1)
    |> MyEnum.tee(&IO.puts/1)
    |> Enum.map(&String.upcase/1)
    |> Enum.each(&IO.puts/1)
```

I works (and It was didactically very useful, for me, to wrote this code), but I'm wondering

1. if there is something built-in in the standard library
2. if my hand-made solution is a good and idiomatic solution in Elixir

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Stream.each](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Stream.html#each/2) will do what you want but you will need to consume the stream to trigger the effects.

> Executes the given function for each item.
>
> Useful for adding side effects (like printing) to a stream.

```
people 
|> Enum.map(&String.upcase/1) 
|> Stream.each(&IO.inspect/1) 
|> Enum.to_list
```

Comment: `Enum.map` → [`Stream.map/2`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/master/Stream.html#map/2)?